# How to get tpope/vim-rails gf command to work with SpaceVim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, vim-plugin, spacevim

I am using SpaceVim as Ruby on Rails IDE and installed the **tpope/vim-rails** plugin. However, the other commands like :Econtroller, :Emodel, :find, commands are working just fine but the **gf** command provided by this plugin is not working in SpaceVim.

It shows me with an error message.

```
# for partial
Can't find file "users/edit_form" in path

# with association
User has_many :notes
Can't find file "notes" in path
```

Also I noticed that for

```
has_one :user,
belongs_to :user
```

`gf` works fine.

But don't work for

```
has_many :users
```

For partial if I change

```
<%= render partial: 'partial_name' %>
```

to

```
<%= render partial: '_partial_name' %>
```

then `gf` works fine.

Comment: What does `:map gf` say? Does it show any mappings?

Comment: Output of :map gf:   

**n  gf          * gf**, 
**n  g             [G]**

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: Thank you @filbranden for your suggestion.

Comment: Add the path where your files are locate using `set path+=/ur/file/path`.

Comment: @dlmeetei, are you telling me to set the path to root directory of the project or setting the PATH for individual files? __set path+=/home/usr/.../project_root/app/views/view_dir/__ didn't work for me.

Comment: @BipinManandhar, Assuming the file path you want to do `gf` is in the hierarchy of root dir, then you can do `set path+=**`, then try :)

Comment: :!pwd show me the root directory of my project. And per your suggestion **set path+=\*\*** didn't work either. Thank you for your answer @dlmeetei